# Webpack CommonChunkPlugin generates empty commons file

Tags: webpack

I'm using webpack 1.14.0 and I'm having problems getting the `CommonsChunkPlugin` to work the way I intend.

I have a config file similar to this (I simplified it):

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    context : __dirname,

    output: {
        filename: "[name].dist-[chunkhash].js",
        chunkFilename: "chunk.[id]-[chunkhash].js",
        path: 'js/min',
        publicPath: '/js/min/',
        pathinfo: true
    },

    // Entry points for the application
    entry : {
        "homepage": "/a/b/homepage.js",
        "contact": "/a/b/contact.js",
        "list": "/a/b/list.js"
    },

    resolve: {
        packageAlias: false,
        alias: {
            "jquery": "/a/b/jquery",
            "dependency-1": "/a/b/dependency-1",
            "dependency-2": "/a/b/dependency-2"
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "commons",
            filename:"commons.js",
            minChunks: 3
        })
    ]
};
```

As I understand, the CommonsChunkPlugin will analyze the entry points and other resulting chunk files, search for duplicated modules and put them in a new "commons" chunk.

I'm following these [examples](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html) and can't get anything else than a commons.js file without any modules inside.

All I get is:

- The collection of `entry points`.
- A lot of `chunk` files (dependencies of the entry points as I understand)
- a `common.js` which only contains the implementation of webpack methods.

This leads me to the following question: I am understanding the target of CommonsChunkPlugin properly?
Does it only analyses entry points and omits chunks? 
90% of my modules are defined in `AMD`, does this affect my results?